# Mapbox Offline and Syncing

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Thanks to the Mapbox Team for the [latest offline support](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/) (see [android support](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#gradle))

One question: If you want offline support but you also want any updates to your mapbox server side data to synchronize with a previous saved client side offline version, is that automatically support?

In other words,

- Client A saves an offline region on DAY 1
- The Data  on the mapbox server is updated on DAY 2
- Client A is online for a bit on DAY 3 and is viewing their Offline Region
- Will Client A see the Server updates or their previously saved region.

It appears they will see the previously saved region and not see the updates.

If so, is there a sync'ing mode where the region will work offline but also receive updates when online and be stored for offline from then on?

The use case is a user has bad connectivity but once in a while is connected and wants the latest data without having to explicitly re-download.

If this is not supported, can it be easily done by we programmers :)

Comment: Does this not answer the question? https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/#use-offline-resources - `If the device has network connectivity, the Mapbox Mobile SDK will make periodic network requests in order to revalidate cached tiles and other resources if the Cache-Control or Expires HTTP response headers indicate that revalidation is desired. If an updated resource is available, it will replace the previous version in the offline database.`

Comment: @MorrisonChang Wow, I missed that.  Yes that seems to mean that it is not only offline but re-synced when online.  Beautiful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct in saying that when client A is back online his offline map will be updated to the most recent on Mapbox server. Glad you like the feature!

Comment: thanks so much. Related question  is I'd like to pre-can an offline  map in my Android app before I send it to the Play Store is that a supported use case?   And if so is there an example of doing this?   It would make the app bigger in the store but it may save time for the user

Comment: Hey Ralph, bundling maps with your apk isn't currently available. We do have an [issue open](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3894) on Github that you can track as we work towards making this feature available.